# send variables to bind_param error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query I need to MYSQL query ignore empty variable in WHERE clause and send send variables to `bind_param`

here is the code

```
<?php
    /**
     * Created by PhpStorm.
     * User: YousefAltaf
     * Date: 11/1/2015
     * Time: 11:40 AM
     */

    //post vars
    $institute = $_POST['institute'];

    if (isset($_POST['sections'])) {
        $sections = $_POST['sections'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['division'])) {
        $division = $_POST['division'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['level'])) {
        $level = $_POST['level'];
    }

    //check empty var
    $where = "WHERE a.institute =?";
    $bind = "i";
    $prams = "$"."institute, ";
    if (!empty($sections)) {
        $where .= " AND a.section =?";
        $bind .= "i";
        $prams .= "$"."sections, ";
    }

    if (!empty($division)) {
        $where .= " AND a.division =?";
        $bind .= "i";
        $prams .= "$"."division, ";
    }

    if (!empty($level)) {
        $where .= " AND a.phase =?";
        $bind .= "i";
        $prams .= "$"."level";
    }

    //var_dump($institute, $sections, $division, $level);
    var_dump($bind);
    print_r ($prams);
    if ($getSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT
    a.*, a.id AS stud_id, b.id, b.ins_name, c.id, c.sec_name, d.id, d.div_name
    FROM student_basic_info AS a
    JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
    CROSS JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id)
    CROSS JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id)
    $where GROUP BY a.id
    ")
    ) {

        $studSearch = array();
        $getSearch->bind_param('iii', $prams);

    } else {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);
    }
    if ($getSearch->execute()) {
        $results = $getSearch->get_result();
        while ($vStud = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            $studSearch[] = $vStud;
            ?>
```

got

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: `if (!empty($level)) {
        $where .= " AND a.phase =?";
        $bind .= "i";
        $prams .= "$"."level";
    }` is it right? confusing

Comment: yes it's, it's just looking if it's posted or not

Comment: `if ($getSearch = $db->prepare("SELECT
    a.*, a.id AS stud_id, b.id, b.ins_name, c.id, c.sec_name, d.id, d.div_name
    FROM student_basic_info AS a
    JOIN institutes AS b ON (a.institute = b.id)
    CROSS JOIN ins_sections AS c ON (a.section = c.id)
    CROSS JOIN ins_division AS d ON (a.division = d.id)
    WHERE a.phase =:i AND a.level =:i GROUP BY a.id
   ")` and `$getSearch->bind_param('ii', array(2,3)) just for example;
`

Comment: @A-2-A one of the suggestion was `$prams is 1 string containing 3 values, you need 3 strings containing 1 value each. So 4 separate parameters for your bind function in this case.` it may help you
in fact I didn't understand how to bind each value individually :(

Comment: Could you show us the whole SQL query string you're trying to modify please?